# alternative to sending email using gmail with firebase function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I recently got that email from Google  which says that as the beginning of 30.05.2022, we will not be able to use "less secure apps" options anymore.

I'm using this option to sending emails with firebase function combined with nodemailer, as probably a lot of other users do.

So the question that I have is how can we use it after the above date?

If you need an example of how I am using it please let me know in the comment.

Comment: What's the correlation between your app sending emails and your app using the 'less secure' setting? There are 1000 ways to send emails so without knowing your specific use case (your code!) it would be impossible to answer. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You may use the Google App Password to replace your current password set inside your nodemailer function

Google App Password will generate 16-digit passcode for your third party app

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en-GB